# git 2 version of file in local and remote

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a config.php file with my configuration (for example, the MySQL credentials).
Those credentials are different in my local version and in the production server (in the local MySQL, I use user root, and in the production server, the user max).
I want to manage it with git. I need to push and pull every file but not the config.php.
I found this command :

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config.php
```

but can I change the remote config.php file (for example, if I change the remote password)? And how to change the local config.php file without affecting the remote?
Should I put this file to the .gitignore?

Answer (score -1):

You could add the file to the `.gitignore file`, assuming it hasn't been committed yet and in case the file is being tracked then you can follow  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) solution in order to remove the file from files being tracked by `git` and once you do that, the changes made within your local `config.php` file will not be tracked by `git`. So before you add it to the `.gitignore file` my recommendation would be:

1. In case the file is already being tracked (which I am assuming is the case) then update the `config.php` with the remote server details and push, then set back the local details and follow  [these steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) to stop tracking the `config.php` file and add it to the `.gitignore file`.

**NOTE** The above approach assumes that you donot plan to and won't change the `remote config.php` details in future.

2. Alternatively create blocks/functions within your `config.php` file that store the details of the `local` setup and `remote` setup then add a `PHP` file or probably another `code` block within the `config.php` file that checks the `base_url` to determine which config details to run. in this case you wouldn't need to add the `config.php` to the `.gitignore file`.

Comment: `.gitignore` file only prevents _new_ files from being added. As soon as a file is tracked, changes will always show up.

Comment: In that case, you can stop the tracking of the file and then add it to the `.gitignore` According to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) you can be able to do that.